# Generating integer partitions

Tags: performance, beginner, rust, iterator

I've tried to implement integer partition algorithm as described in blogpost below (author implemented it in Python):
[Generating integer partitions](http://jeromekelleher.net/generating-integer-partitions.html)

I'm still trying to learn best practices in producing clean code. I would also be thankful for any performance tips.

My code:

```
struct NumberPartition {
    a: Vec<i32>,
    k: i32,
    y: i32,
    x: i32,
    l: i32,
}

impl NumberPartition {
    pub fn new(n: i32) -> Self {
        NumberPartition {
            a: vec![0; (n + 1) as usize],
            k: 1,
            y: n - 1,
            x: 0,
            l: 0
        }
    }


    fn partition(&mut self) -> Option<Vec<Vec<i32>>> {
        let mut buf: Vec<Vec<i32>> = Vec::new();
        while self.k != 0 {
            self.x = self.a[(self.k - 1) as usize] + 1;
            self.k -= 1;
            while 2 * self.x <= self.y {
                self.a[self.k as usize] = self.x;
                self.y -= self.x;
                self.k += 1;
            }
            self.l = self.k + 1;
            while self.x <= self.y {
                self.a[self.k as usize] = self.x;
                self.a[self.l as usize] = self.y;
                buf.push(self.a[..(self.k + 2) as usize].to_vec());
                self.x += 1;
                self.y -= 1;
            }
            self.a[self.k as usize] = self.x + self.y;
            self.y = self.x + self.y - 1;
            buf.push(self.a[..(self.k + 1) as usize].to_vec());
        }
        Some(buf)
    }
}


fn main() {
    let b = NumberPartition::new(6).partition();
    for i in b.iter() {
        println!("{:?}", i);
    }
}
```

Comment: a double yield is painful to implement as an iterator: https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ff3a2402cbc8155a6b90bdbbd18043fe.

Comment: @Stargateur yes indeed, i tried it and had to think of something else. Your code is great! Thank you!

Comment: Various small changes on that iterator: https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c56efff9af698cb04a54fac3f1cb01c5

Comment: Since partitions only deal with positive integers, you should probably use an unsigned type like `u32` or `u64`, and also add a check against `NumberPartiton::new(0)`.

Comment: I tried to simplify it further: https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=35e5b00918ef0ccbc4b74d02f79cd545

Comment: For what it's worth, I think the performance of internal iteration could be improved here by implementing `try_fold` on the iterator. But it's already really fast.